# Django server response bad request 400(Apache) in show display page when DEBUG=False

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

When I run the django server apache with DEBUG = True, it's running perfectly. But when I change DEBUG to False can not show URLS page , I see questions of stackoverflow of this , but any result for me,
(Django vertsion : 1.9.2),
I set :

```
DEBUG = False
TEMPLATES_DEBUG = DEBUG
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
```

also,

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost",".domain.com" and etc ...]
```

Comment: Any error in the apache log files?

Comment: No. i test localhost there is this issue,

Comment: No log files? You should configure apache to write log files

Comment: i test localhost without apache i get this issue of custom error,

Comment: Are you using `python manage.py runserver`? Because in your question you wrote something about `apache server`. Does `python manage.py shell` give any error messages?

Comment: yes,any error message , i just use custom error when use DEBUG=False can not display my URLS of urls.py , but use DEBUG=True work and show my site page

Comment: What does `python manage.py shell` say?

Comment: Nothing,running python interprater

Comment: Did you try `python manage.py check`?

Comment: show error "django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 0")"

Comment: So you have connections problems to your db.